# Matthew 26:24: What's the meaning of "goes" in "the Son of man goes as it is written of him"?

Tags: matthew, layers-of-meaning

Matthew 26:24:

> The Son of man **goeth** as it is written of him: but woe unto that man by
>   whom the Son of man is betrayed! it had been good for that man if he
>   had not been born. (KJV)

What's the meaning of the verb translated here as "goes"? I mean, Jesus here was referring to Himself as "the Son of man", so that means that He was saying that He was "going". But going in what sense? If the meaning is "coming" then how is it that He was still coming while He was already there with all His disciples?

Could it be that the meaning is "going away"?

Or, perhaps, some other meaning is implied, which is neither "coming", nor "going", but something else?

Comment: Are you asking for specific Greek translation of that word?

Comment: @North - Rather, about the scope of possible meanings that that word of the original language had in the time of writing.

Comment: υπαγο, _hupago_, is translated 55 times in the KJV as merely 'go' but, significantly, also 17 times as 'go one's way' [from Young's Analytical Concordance]. So 'the Son of man _goes his way_ as it is written of him' may be appropriate, here.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, when Jesus says "goeth" he's referring to the fact that he is going to the cross. When studying biblical words, it's improtant to look at the section as a whole, rather than picking specific verses.

Now this is a very good question. The greek word for "goeth" as translated in KJV is the word "ὑπάγω" (hupago). This word in itself is translated I go, depart, begone, or in some extreme cases, die. However, this is a very strong word, and is only used as an *imperative* verb. The word itself means "to lead under, bring under". Basically this word is used only when being *commanded* by somebody to go (you go, I go [because someone told me to], etc.). The same word is used in multiple occasions in the New Testament, such as in Matthew 8:13, "Go! It will be done just as you believed you would" (NIV). And in Matthew 16:23, the same word is used when Jesus says to Peter, "Get behind me Satan!" (NIV). All used as commands.

Source: http://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/26-24.htm
http://biblehub.com/greek/5217.htm

Comment: So yes, to answer your other question, the word means going away, or more specifically lead away

Comment: Please provide evidence for your assertion from a primary source. Since we are dealing with the definition of a word it would be appropriate to supply the entry for the word in a koine lexicon. Please let me know if you have trouble locating a primary source. Thanks.

Comment: @Ruminator thanks. I'll add more links when I can find it.

Comment: Small correction... hupagw is not an imperative. It is the first person nominative.  "I go [obediently]". A person more knowledgable than I in Greek might want to tweak that.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus is going to the cross as it has been foretold by the prophets since Genesis 3:15.  He is not Christ unless His life matches that of the Messianic prophecies.

Comment: Welcome to BHSE! Please make sure you take our Tour. (See below left) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

The Son of man (the eternal life of Jesus being made manifest in our mortal flesh) goes away….shrinks out of sight from this earth…. by those who are following in the footsteps of Judas even today as a great multitude was with and still is with Judas in the betrayal.

> Matthew 26:24-25 KJV (24)  ***The Son of man goeth as it is written of
>   him: but woe unto that man by whom the Son of man is betrayed!*** it had
>   been good for that man if he had not been born. (25)  Then Judas,
>   which betrayed him, answered and said, Master, is it I? He said unto
>   him, Thou hast said.

They come to take the real Jesus out of our lives with flattery/deceit and false preaching which removes the keeping of His "daily" sacrifice out of our lives so that His life that was coming in our mortal flesh shrinks away.

We are to keep the “daily” sacrifice of the Lord Jesus ….ALWAYS bearing about in our body the dying of Him….so that the eternal life of Jesus is made manifest in our outer mortal flesh.  He gives His flesh for the life of the world….this world that we are living in now.

But the Son of man (that appearing eternal life of Jesus ) is being currently taken away by those who are following in the footsteps of Judas.  His eternal life is not appearing anywhere in this earth as His life withdraws and shrinks out of sight from those who have ceased from doing the “daily” sacrifice .

> 2 Corinthians 4:10-11 KJV (10)  ***Always bearing about in the body the
>   dying of the Lord Jesus, that the life also of Jesus might be made
>   manifest in our body.*** (11)  For we which live are alway delivered unto
>   death for Jesus' sake, **that the life also of Jesus might be made
>   manifest in our mortal flesh.**

There is currently a “great multitude” who are currently taking away this appearing life of Jesus from being made manifest in our mortal bodies in this earth.   If we fall “asleep” to keeping His “daily”, then these men have the power to deceive us as Judas gave a “kiss”….with the flattering lips.  The Son of man is being betrayed into the hands of sinners.

> Mark 14:41-44 KJV (41)  *And he cometh the third time, and saith unto
>   them, Sleep on now, and take your rest: it is enough, the hour is
>   come; behold, **the Son of man is betrayed into the hands of sinners.**
>   (42)  Rise up, let us go; lo, he that betrayeth me is at hand. (43) 
>   And immediately, while he yet spake, cometh Judas, one of the twelve,
>   and **with him a great multitude with swords and staves,** from the chief
>   priests and the scribes and the elders. (44)  And he that betrayed him
>   had given them a token, saying, **Whomsoever I shall kiss, that same is
>   he; take him, and lead him away safely**.*

They come out to us with “swords”:   causing divisions among us with the preaching of their various handwritings of  church “dogmas” – what one thinks is right…what one believes is right.   They have their many different documents….their tenets of faith of what they “ believe” is right.

These things divide us as many fight and war over them as they judge each other using the handwritings of men which serves THE lie and they perish with the serving and worshipping of their various handwritings of ordinances instead of worshipping God.

They also come out with “staves”….Greek: “xulon” meaning “timber”….that is, crosses.

They come preaching many “another Jesus’s” instead of the real Jesus who died on the cross.

Yet, their “Jesus” that they are preaching is not the real Christ…but is the “antichrist”…the “instead-of-Christ” even though they are proclaiming that the “Jesus”  that they are preaching is the true Christ (“I am the Christ”).

If we keep the DAILY sacrifice of Jesus, they have no power to take hold of the real Jesus out of our lives:    “I sat DAILY (sacrifice) with you teaching in the temple ( our mortal body) and you lay no hold on Me”.

> Matthew 26:55 KJV (55)  *In that same hour said Jesus to the
>   multitudes, Are ye come out as against a thief with swords and staves
>   for to take me? **I sat daily with you teaching in the temple, and ye
>   laid no hold on me.***

But they use the “power of darkness” to deceive us when we go to “sleep”….not  remembering to always keep His daily sacrifice in our lives.

Mark these men who follow in the footsteps of Judas and avoid them.  They come with the flattering lips to deceive us as they use “good words and fair speeches”.  It is a feigned “kiss” and not a holy one.   Salute one another with a holy kiss….not a feigned kiss of the flattering lips.

> Romans 16:16-18 KJV (16)  **Salute one another with an holy kiss.** The
>   churches of Christ salute you.

They come with “swords”….causing divisions and offenses contrary to the doctrine of the true Christ.

> (17)  **Now I beseech you, brethren, mark them which cause divisions and
>   offences contrary to the doctrine which ye have learned; and avoid
>   them.**

They preach things that they ought not be for money’s sake…serving their own belly rather than the true Jesus…our Lord Jesus Christ.

> (18)  *For they that are such serve not our Lord Jesus Christ, but
>   their own belly; **and by good words and fair speeches deceive the
>   hearts of the simple**.*

Avoid these men who follow in the footsteps of Judas.  Their end is mortal destruction of the body from this earth.  Judas strangled himself.  “Hanged” = Apagchomai  = “to strangle oneself off”.

> Matthew 27: (5)  And he cast down the pieces of silver in the temple,
>   and departed, **and went and hanged himself.**

We must abstain from things “strangled”.  We must avoid those who are going in the way of Judas whose end is destruction as they preach lifeless words.   Their end is destruction …so we do not want to be there in the company of them sharing their common end as they perish from this earth.

They do not acknowledge in their preaching that the eternal life of Jesus is coming in our mortal flesh now and is to be made manifest in our mortal bodies in this earth.

They do not preach the doctrine of the true Jesus who is THE Christ but preach things that are of the spirit/breath of “another Jesus” the “antichrist” ….the instead/substitution of the true Christ whom Satan uses to make war with the people of God.

The multitudes who follow after Judas come to take away the keeping of the “daily” sacrifice of our Lord Jesus Christ out of our lives so that His eternal life is never made manifest in this earth.

He is coming in our mortal flesh…but if we listen to those who follow after Judas, then His life shrinks away out of sight as they take His eternal life away from being manifest.  His appearing eternal life is being cut off from this earth by them. Who can declare His generation?

We are not to receive them as they beguile us of our reward:  the appearing eternal life of Jesus in this current mortal body in this earth.

> 2 John 1:7-11 KJV (7)  ***For many deceivers are entered into the world,
>   who confess not that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh. This is a
>   deceiver and an antichrist.*** (8)  Look to yourselves, that we lose not
>   those things which we have wrought, but that we receive a full reward.
>   (9)  Whosoever transgresseth, and abideth not **in the doctrine of
>   Christ, hath not God. He that abideth in the doctrine of Christ, he
>   hath both the Father and the Son.** (10)  **If there come any unto you,
>   and bring not this doctrine, receive him not into your house**, neither
>   bid him God speed: (11)  For he that biddeth him God speed is partaker
>   of his evil deeds.

The many false prophets are not acknowledging in any of their preaching that Jesus Christ IS COMING now in the flesh…in our mortal flesh.   This is the test to see if they are of God or not.

> *1 John 4:1-3 KJV (1)  Beloved, believe not every spirit, but try the
>   spirits whether they are of God: **because many false prophets are gone
>   out into the world. (2)  Hereby know ye the Spirit of God: Every
>   spirit that confesseth that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh is of
>   God:***

They are not preaching the doctrine of the true Christ (that Jesus Christ IS COMING now in our mortal flesh)  but are preaching with the breath of the antichrist that Jesus SHALL COME someday in the future.

We have all heard it being preached in many churches today:   that their “Jesus” is coming some day in the future.  There are many Jesus’s the “antichrists” being preach today who are supposedly coming someday in the future.

They are not looking for His eternal life to be coming in our mortal flesh presently which appears there when we keep the “daily” sacrifice of our Lord Jesus Christ in the body.  They instead remove the keeping of the “daily” so that the Son of man…His life… withdraws and is extinguished out of our lives as His eternal life never is made manifest in our mortal flesh.

> (3)  ***And every spirit that confesseth not that Jesus Christ is come in
>   the flesh is not of God: and this is that spirit of antichrist,***
>   whereof ye have heard **that it should come;** and even now already is it
>   in the world.

Their “prince”…their “another Jesus”…is being preached that he SHALL COME some day in the future when Jesus, the Prince of Life, IS COMING now in our mortal flesh.

The people of the prince that “SHALL COME” are not looking for the true Christ coming in our mortal bodies by the keeping of His “daily sacrifice” ….always bearing about in the mortal body the dying of the Lord Jesus Christ.

They remove the keeping of His “daily” sacrifice out of our lives so that His life never appears in this earth. It sinks away out of sight in this earth because of this.    They destroy the city and the sanctuary.  The place of His sanctuary (the mortal body) is being cast down to the grave.

> Daniel 9:26 KJV (26)  *And after threescore and two weeks shall Messiah
>   be cut off, but not for himself: a**nd the people of the prince that
>   shall come shall** destroy the city and the sanctuary; and the end
>   thereof shall be with a flood, and unto the end of the war desolations
>   are determined.*

His eternal life is being cut off out of the land of the living. Who can declare His generation?

> Isaiah 53:7-9 KJV (7)  *He was oppressed, and he was afflicted, yet he
>   opened not his mouth: he is brought as a lamb to the slaughter, and as
>   a sheep before her shearers is dumb, so he openeth not his mouth. (8) 
>   He was taken from prison and from judgment: **and who shall declare his
>   generation? for he was cut off out of the land of the living:** for the
>   transgression of my people was he stricken.*

He made his grave with the wicked and with the rich in His DEATHS…plural….as His eternal life is being extinguished out of the lives of so many of His people as the false prophets are preaching things that they ought not be for money’s sake.   They practice and prosper at it.

> (9)  *And he made his grave with the wicked, and with the rich **in his
>   death(S)**; because he had done no violence, neither was any deceit in his
>   mouth.*

The Son of man is betrayed by them and is being extinguished as His life (the Son of man) shrinks out of view from this earth .

Crucified = figuratively “extinguished”.   His eternal life is being extinguished from this earth by deception. The Prince of Life is being crucified/extinguished/killed even now though God had already raised Him from the dead.  See Acts 3:15.

> Matthew 26:2-5 KJV (2)  *Ye know that after two days is the feast of
>   the passover, **and the Son of man is betrayed to be crucified.** (3) 
>   Then assembled together the chief priests, and the scribes, and the
>   elders of the people, unto the palace of the high priest, who was
>   called Caiaphas,*

They take THE (definite article) real Jesus out of our lives by deceit (beguiling us of our reward) and destroy His eternal  life out of those whom they are deceiving.

> (4)  ***And consulted that they might take Jesus by subtilty, and kill
>   him.*** (5)  But they said, Not on the feast day, lest there be an uproar
>   among the people.

We must believe and confess that the real Jesus is the Christ the true Son of God who gives us an understanding  rather than many “another Jesus’s” whom the many false prophets are preaching today as they come out to us in false “peace” giving us  a feigned “kiss” but lead us to our mortal destruction from this earth.

Beware of false prophets as they will lead us down the broad to the destruction of the mortal flesh from this earth.  They pose as ministers of righteousness…preaching their handwritings of church dogmas which leads us to judging others using the handwritings as a basis for doing such things…. not doing unto others as you would have them doing unto you.

> Matthew 7:12-15 KJV (12)  *Therefore all things whatsoever ye would
>   that men should do to you, do ye even so to them: for this is the law
>   and the prophets. (13)  Enter ye in at the strait gate: **for wide is
>   the gate, and broad is the way, that leadeth to destruction, and many
>   there be which go in thereat:** (14)  Because strait is the gate, and
>   narrow is the way, which leadeth unto life, and few there be that find
>   it. (15)  **Beware of false prophets, which come to you in sheep's
>   clothing, but inwardly they are ravening wolves**.*